# Formatting number in lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am using a lookup column in a library that is formatting the number to look like this:

[image: Days Open lookup column on library]

On the list column it's pulling from, the data looks like this (which is the desired result):

[image: Days Open column on list]

**Is there a formatting schema I can use to make the lookup column look like the original Days Open column?**

For additional info, here's how the Days Open column is set up:

[image: Days Open column information]

Answer (score 0):

Use below JSON code to format your lookup column:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=floor(@currentField.lookupValue)"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

You can use either `floor()` or `ceiling()` operator as per your requirements. Check below documentation for more information about operators available in JSON formatting:

[JSON formatting Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators)